# OpenLayers Vector Features/Layer invisible (do not render)

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I cant understand why styled vector layer is invisible? It seems like it has no features, but why? There is mistake in this code? OSM, Google Layers is visible and I can swith them in LayerSwitcher (and Overlay "Vectorlayer" also present there). URL to icon is correct.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Index</title>
        <link href="/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
function Startit() {
    var dislon = 30.4958316666667;
    var dislat = 59.9168383333333;
    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(dislon, dislat);
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map({div: "mapcontent",projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")});
    var maposm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM");
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google", { numZoomLevels: 20 });
    var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Earth", { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20 });
    map.addLayers([maposm, gmap, ghyb]);
    lonlat.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
    map.setCenter(lonlat, 11);
    var lSwitch = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
    map.addControl(lSwitch);
    var sdLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("VectorLayer");
    var cStyle = { externalGraphic: "/images/icons/blue.png", graphicWidth: 35, graphicHeight: 35 };
    var currPoint = OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(dislon,dislat);
    var ft = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(currPoint, null, cStyle);
    map.addLayer(sdLayer);
    sdLayer.addFeatures([ft]);
}
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="Startit();">
        <div id="mapcontent" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

=) Omg! It was just stupid mistake >>>  var currPoint = **new** OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(dislon,dislat);